# AND OR SQL operator with multiple records

Tags: sql, hive

I have the following query where if brand1/camp1 taken individually, query returns the correct value but if I specify more than one brand or campaigns, it returns some other number and I am not sure what the math is behind that. It is not the total of the two either.

I think it is `IN` operator that is specifying `OR` with "," as opposed to what I require it to do which is consider `AND`

```
select campaign,
sum(case when campaign in ('camp1', 'camp2') and description in ('brand1', 'brand2') then orders else 0 end) as brand_convs
   from data.camp_results   
where campaign in ('camp1', 'camp2') and channel='prog' and type='sbc'
group by campaign
having brand_convs > 0
order by brand_convs desc;
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you want to get the order sum only when the description matches the campaign (camp1+brand1 or camp2+brand2) or is campaign=camp1 and description=brand2 acceptable?

Comment: The first one, camp1 has to match brand1. It can't be an or situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `IN` part as you suspected: The two `IN` operators do not affect eachother in any way, so `campaign` can be `camp1` while `description` is `brand2`.

If your DBMS supports multiple columns in an `IN` statement, you use a single `IN` statement:

```
SELECT campaign, SUM(
    CASE WHEN (campaign, description) IN (
        ('camp1', 'brand1'),
        ('camp2', 'brand2')
    ) THEN orders ELSE 0 END
) [rest of query...]
```

If not, you're probably going to have to use `AND`s and `OR`s

```
SELECT campaign, SUM(
    CASE WHEN
        (campaign='camp1' AND description='brand1')
        OR (campaign='camp2' AND description='brand2')
    THEN orders ELSE 0 END
) [rest of query...]
```

Comment: The latter one worked :) Thanks for your help. Never thought of the using the "OR" operator, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, don't forget to mark the correct/most helpful answer as accepted. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work